# How can I edit this code for user input and to end at 0?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Type in a whole number!: " && read X
x=1
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
  echo x
x=$(( $x - 1 ))
done
```

I want this script to have a user input a number and have it countdown from that number "x" and stop at 0. I have no clue why it just infinitely keeps going and doesn't stop at 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `bash`, you can make use of some features that might not be available in POSIX `/bin/sh`. For example:

1. `read` accepts a prompt string, eliminating the need for a separate `printf`

   ```
   read -p 'Type in a whole number!: ' x
   ```
2. you can use arithmetic expressions like `(( x > 0 ))` in place of `[ x -gt 0 ]` test brackets, and postfix decrement like `((x--))`
3. bash has an `until` construct that might be more idiomatic for a count down

So for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Type in a whole number!: ' x

until (( x == -1 )); do
  printf '%d\n' $((x--))
done
```

ex.

```
$ ./myscript
Type in a whole number!: 5
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: even if == -1 is perfectly fine I would prefer < 0 like you use in your explanation just incase.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, your code `x=$(( $x - 1 ))` means "substract 1 to `x`", then this happens:

```
x=1

loop 1
x=$(( 1 - 1 )) # = 0

loop 2
x=$(( 0 - 1 )) # = -1
```

and so on

So the condition that `x` is less or equal to five is met forever. So what you mean is *add* 1 to `x`, not *substract*.

Another thing is that your `echo` echoes the string `x`, not the value of `x`, so it should be

```
echo $x
```

You will see the result of `x` this way (add `sleep 1`):

```
Type in a whole number!: # typed 1
1
0
-1
-2
...
```

The other thing is that you set the variable `X` (capital) in your `read`, but then you want to use (I assume) that variable, so your code should read:

```
printf "Type in a whole number!: " && read X
#x=1
while [ $X -le 5 ]
do
  echo $X
X=$(( $X + 1 ))
done
```

So, executing the script:

```
Type in a whole number!: # typed 1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I just need it to countdown from the user input, that's why I had  ```x=$(( $x - 1 ))```  and then have it end at 0, I changed what you said and it's much smoother but what I have just keeps going in the negative.

Comment: So the output would be something like

Comment: ```Type in a whole number!: # typed 10                                                                                                  10                                                                                                                                              9                                                                                                                                                          8                                                                                                                                                7 ```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a C-style `for` loop. In bash that looks like:

```bsh
read -p "Enter a number: " x
for (( ; x >= 0; x-- )); do
  echo $x
done
```

Or you can use `seq`:

```
seq "$x" -1 0
```